# restrict upside down in iPad

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, xcode6

I disabled the upside down orientation in iPhone device though TARGET>GENERAL>DEPLOYMENT->DEVICE ORIENTATION but its not disabled in iPad.Please tell how to disable upside down orienatation in ipad

Comment: Are you using navigation controller as your rootviewcontroller on window?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIViewController *topVC = self.topViewController;
    return topVC.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried this but - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations get never called